# How do I calculate the difference between two time values in Excel?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, date-time

Using Excel 2007, how do I calculate the time difference by entering

- a start time
- an end time

What format do I use in the cells where the time is?

For example, I'd like to be able to enter `0800` and *see* `0800` in the box, or enter `1430` and see `1430` in the box.  Then I'd like to have the formula box display the time lapsed in hours and minutes.

- `A1 = 0800`
- `A2 = 1430`
- `A3 (A1-A2) = 6.30*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula on **A3**:

```
=TEXT(A2,"00\:00")+(TEXT(A1,"00\:00")>TEXT(A2,"00\:00"))-TEXT(A1,"00\:00")
```

It should also account for durations that cross midnight (see example below). You can enter times in **A1** or **A2** without colons.

In the example below, A1 contains the *Start* time and A2 contains the *End* time.

[image]

**Number Formats used:**
**A1**: *Custom* > `0000`
**A2**: *Custom* > `0000`
**A3**: *Custom* > `[h]:mm` or `h.mm` (based on your example)

If you want to compute for hour fractions instead (i.e. `2.50` hours instead of `2:30`), set **A3**'s number format to **General** and then change the formula to:

```
=24*(TEXT(A2,"00\:00")+(TEXT(A1,"00\:00")>TEXT(A2,"00\:00"))-TEXT(A1,"00\:00"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, but it still requires the numbers to have been typed with colons (i.e. 8:00 instead of 800)

[image]

Comment: The OP wants to have the time displayed as `0800` though.

Comment: Use Type hhmm in the Custom section

Answer (score 1):

Just type them in normally, with colons, and use standard addition/subtraction:

[image]

Then, select the range, and under `number format` on the Home tab, click the dropdown and choose `more number formats`.

[image]

In the resulting dialog, set the format to `hhmm` (in other words, remove the colon from the default time format).

[image]

Now, your times will be formatted without the colon, and the subtraction will take care of calculating the time difference.

Unfortunately, you will still have to enter times with the colon, but they will display without it. If you enter the time without the colon, Excel thinks it's a date, and will break the setup.

Answer (score -1):

=minute(C1-C2)   will give you minutes of difference between the two time in cells C1 and C2. Make sure the cells C1 and c2 have the format of "Time"